# How to display numbers in two rows using for loop?

Tags: jsp, for-loop

```
<%
        int apps = 13;
        out.println("<div>");
        out.println("<table>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        for (int i = 1; i <= apps; i++) {
            out.println("<td>");
            out.println("" + i + "");
        }
        out.println("</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
    %>
```

for this i'm getting output as 1 2 ....13 but i need output as 
**1 3 5 7 9 11 13** in `one row` and remaining in `second row`
**2 4 6 8 10 12**  .How can i do like this? if i have apps=100 output needs in same fashion.inside table values must in two rows.Thanks for your help.

Comment: hey if you want to display the only odd(if) nos or otherwise (else)even nos... like @jjpa

Comment: did you try my code or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
<%
    int apps = 13;
    out.println("<div>");
    out.println("<table>");
    Stringbuilder firstRow = new StringBuilder();
    firstRow.append("<tr>");
    Stringbuilder secondRow = new StringBuilder();
    secondRow.append("<tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= apps; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 1 ) {
            firstRow.append("<td>"+i+"</td>")
        }else {
            secondRow.append("<td>"+i+"</td>");
        }
    }
    firstRow.append("</tr>");
    secondRow.append("</tr>");
    out.println(firstRow.toString());
    out.println(secondRow.toString());
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</div>");
%>
```

by checking the value id odd or even you can append it to the respective StringBuilder object and then print it out.

Comment: @jjpa he(@user3297398), wants to say in his post like want to display the odd no and even numbers also, then how did works your solutions, that not possible...

Comment: whats the use of Stingbuilder and append functionality here,could you explain me please?

Comment: String is immutable.  StringBuilder objects are like String objects, except that they can be modified. Read about string builder [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)

Comment: @jmail Sorry didn't understand what you said. I have given solution with odd and even.

Answer (score 0):

**source:@JJPA**

try this one...

```
<%
    int apps = 13;
    out.println("<div>");
    out.println("<table>");
    Stringbuilder firstRow = new StringBuilder();
    firstRow.append("<tr>");
    Stringbuilder secondRow = new StringBuilder();
    secondRow.append("<tr>");
    out.println("<tr>");
    for (int i = 1; i <= apps; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 1 ) {
            firstRow.append("<td>"+i+"</td>");

        }
        if(i % 2 == 0 ) {
            secondRow.append("<td>"+i+"</td>");

        }
    }
    firstRow.append("</tr>");
    secondRow.append("</tr>");
    out.println(firstRow.toString());
    out.println(secondRow.toString());
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</div>");
%>
```